# Why do my scrapyard profits stop at 5000?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My GTA character Michael owns the scrapyard, and, when I get to a certain amount of money, it **stops**. As soon as I hit 5,000 in game dollars the income stops there for the week. Is this a bug, or can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

The scrapyard's income is capped at $5000 per week. Destroying even more cars beyond this won't give you any money- you have to wait another week.